# in Sequelize after create add in response "val": "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" instance of time(2019-03-22 09:56:38)

Tags: sequelize.js

In Sequelize after create add in response `"val": "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"` instance of **time(2019-03-22 09:56:38)**
what define in code is described below

**model:**

```
        created_at: {
              type: DataTypes.DATE,
              allowNull: false,
              defaultValue: sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
            },
```

**controller:**

```
    Message.create(
          {
            col: body.col
          },
        ).then((
          const MessageResponse = response.get({
            plain: true,
          });
       res.send(apiSuccessHandler({}, { MessageResponse, message: 'Your request submitted successfully.' }, 200));
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(403).send(apiFailureHandler({ message: "We couldn't save your request, please try again." }, {}, 403));
    });
```

**response:**

```
{
    "resultState": {
        "status": 200,
        "message": "Success"
    },
    "MessageResponse": {
        //what i get
         "created_at": {
            "val": "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
        },
        //my requirement 
        "created_at": 2019-03-22 09:56:38,
        "id": 60,

    },
    "message": "Your request submitted successfully."
}
```

Comment: did you fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the `defaultValue: sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')` in model definition instead it should be in your migration file where you define the table structure.
**in migration file:**

```
createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
}
```

sequelize.literal creates a object representing a literal, i.e. something that will not be escaped.

And when you use `sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')` in model definition it creates an object with `{val: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'}` and assign it to model field. So when you create an model its created_at field contain the literal object and not Date value. and due to that it is returning incorrect value for created_at field.

If you want to pass the default value to your model definition than it should contain the value of the Date directly.

ex: **in Model:**

```
created_at: {
              type: DataTypes.DATE,
              allowNull: false,
              defaultValue: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:s:ss') + '.000Z',
            },
```

Comment: This will determine the default value at interpretation time which means if you're running in a Node server, every defaultValue will just be the time you last restarted the server.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this

```
 Message.create(
      {
        col: body.col,
        created_at: moment(), // add this line
      },
    ).then((
      const MessageResponse = response.get({
        plain: true,
      });
   res.send(apiSuccessHandler({}, { MessageResponse, message: 'Your request submitted successfully.' }, 200));
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
  res.status(403).send(apiFailureHandler({ message: "We couldn't save your request, please try again." }, {}, 403));
});
```

Comment: Kinda defeats the purpose of having a `defaultValue` option...

Answer (score 0):

You can set **defaultValue : DataTypes.NOW** in a model like below

```
createdDateTime: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW
},
```

Alternatively, You can use **moment()**

```
createdDateTime: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: moment()
},
```